# Postgresql REAL type conversion separator

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

Postgresql cannot automatically convert float point data that comes from remote table in format "1,1"

I am trying to connect db2 and postgresql using some fdw extensions. Now I am using odbc_fdw, but odbc always return float types in format "1,1" and postgresql can only use point as delimiter. may be any postgresql settings or odbc configs?

```sql
SELECT CAST('1,01000000E+1' as real);
```

Error code 22P02. Wrong syntax for type real

I expect to automatically convert strings like "1,1" to float using cast. I think without this I won't be able to user foreign tables with float data types

Comment: any reason you can't just `select cast(replace('1,01000000E+1', ',', '.') as real);`

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
SELECT string_to_array('1,01000000E+1', ',')::real[]
```

Comment: result is strange
And I need that postgres can natively convert to rel with comma separator